# better-sqlite3 - Could not locate the bindings file

Tags: better-sqlite3

I saw this was quite a common problem - I'm having issues with better-sqlite3 module (version 7.1.0, node version v15.13.0, on Mac).
I am trying to run yarn install, but receive the following error:

```
error /Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/better-sqlite3: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: prebuild-install || npm run build-release
Arguments: 
Directory: /Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/better-sqlite3
Output:
prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=15.13.0 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=darwin)

> better-sqlite3@7.1.0 build-release
> node-gyp rebuild --release

gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@15.13.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python2
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/avive/.node-gyp/15.13.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/avive/.node-gyp/15.13.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/avive/.node-gyp/15.13.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/better-sqlite3',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.

gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:345:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:369:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/better-sqlite3




warning Error running install script for optional dependency: "/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/fsevents: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node install
Arguments: 
Directory: /Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/fsevents
Output:
node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.10.3
node-pre-gyp info using node@15.13.0 | darwin | x64
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp info check checked for \"/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v88-darwin-x64/fse.node\" (not found)
node-pre-gyp http GET https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.7/fse-v1.2.7-node-v88-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp http 404 https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.7/fse-v1.2.7-node-v88-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.7/fse-v1.2.7-node-v88-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.2.7 and node@15.13.0 (node-v88 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp http 404 status code downloading tarball https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.7/fse-v1.2.7-node-v88-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for fsevents@1.2.7 and node@15.13.0 (node-v88 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error Connection closed while downloading tarball file 
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@15.13.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@15.13.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info ok 
gyp info ok 
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@15.13.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@15.13.0 | darwin | x64
gyp infogyp spawn /usr/bin/python2
 info spawn /usr/bin/python2
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info gypspawn args    'binding.gyp',
infogyp  spawn argsinfo spawn args [
   '-f',
gyp gypinfo  infospawn args    'make',
spawn argsgyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/fsevents/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp    '/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
info spawn args   '/Users/avive/.node-gyp/15.13.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp infogyp spawn args info   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
 gypspawn args    'binding.gyp',
info gypspawn args    '-Dvisibility=default',
infogyp  spawn argsinfo   '-f',
 spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/avive/.node-gyp/15.13.0',
gypgyp  infoinfo  spawn argsspawn args   'make',
   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/node-gyp',
gypgyp  infoinfo  spawn argsspawn args   '-I',
gyp    '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/avive/.node-gyp/15.13.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
infogyp  spawn argsinfo   '/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/fsevents/build/config.gypi',
 spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/fsevents',
gypgyp  info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
spawn args   '/Users/avive/.node-gyp/15.13.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/avive/.node-gyp/15.13.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/avive/.node-gyp/15.13.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/fsevents',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.

gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.

gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:345:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:369:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.5.0
gyp ERR! command \"/usr/local/bin/node\" \"/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js\" \"configure\" \"--fallback-to-build\" \"--module=/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v88-darwin-x64/fse.node\" \"--module_name=fse\" \"--module_path=/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v88-darwin-x64\" \"--napi_version=8\" \"--node_abi_napi=napi\"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v15.13.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:345:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:369:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.5.0
gyp ERR! command \"/usr/local/bin/node\" \"/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js\" \"configure\" \"--fallback-to-build\" \"--module=/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v88-darwin-x64/fse.node\" \"--module_name=fse\" \"--module_path=/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v88-darwin-x64\" \"--napi_version=8\" \"--node_abi_napi=napi\"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v15.13.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v88-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v88-darwin-x64 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:369:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.5.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command \"/usr/local/bin/node\" \"/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp\" \"install\" \"--fallback-to-build\"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v15.13.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v88-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v88-darwin-x64 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)"
info This module is OPTIONAL, you can safely ignore this error
warning Error running install script for optional dependency: "/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node install
Arguments: 
Directory: /Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents
Output:
node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.10.0
node-pre-gyp info using node@15.13.0 | darwin | x64
node-pre-gyp info check checked for \"/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v88-darwin-x64/fse.node\" (not found)
node-pre-gyp http GET https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.4/fse-v1.2.4-node-v88-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp http 404 https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.4/fse-v1.2.4-node-v88-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.4/fse-v1.2.4-node-v88-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.2.4 and node@15.13.0 (node-v88 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp http 404 status code downloading tarball https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.4/fse-v1.2.4-node-v88-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@15.13.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info ok 
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@15.13.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python2
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/avive/.node-gyp/15.13.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/avive/.node-gyp/15.13.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/avive/.node-gyp/15.13.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.

gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:345:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:369:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.5.0
gyp ERR! command \"/usr/local/bin/node\" \"/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js\" \"configure\" \"--fallback-to-build\" \"--module=/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v88-darwin-x64/fse.node\" \"--module_name=fse\" \"--module_path=/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v88-darwin-x64\" \"--napi_version=8\" \"--node_abi_napi=napi\"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v15.13.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v88-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v88-darwin-x64 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:369:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.5.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command \"/usr/local/bin/node\" \"/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp\" \"install\" \"--fallback-to-build\"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v15.13.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v88-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v88-darwin-x64 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)"
info This module is OPTIONAL, you can safely ignore this error

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Also when trying to run a js file that uses that module, I get the error:

```
/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:135
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
 → /Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/better_sqlite3.node
 → /Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/Debug/better_sqlite3.node
 → /Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/Release/better_sqlite3.node
 → /Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/better-sqlite3/out/Debug/better_sqlite3.node
 → /Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/better-sqlite3/Debug/better_sqlite3.node
 → /Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/better-sqlite3/out/Release/better_sqlite3.node
 → /Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/better-sqlite3/Release/better_sqlite3.node
 → /Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/default/better_sqlite3.node
 → /Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/better-sqlite3/compiled/15.13.0/darwin/x64/better_sqlite3.node
 → /Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/better-sqlite3/addon-build/release/install-root/better_sqlite3.node
 → /Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/better-sqlite3/addon-build/debug/install-root/better_sqlite3.node
 → /Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/better-sqlite3/addon-build/default/install-root/better_sqlite3.node
 → /Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/better-sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v88-darwin-x64/better_sqlite3.node
    at bindings (/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:126:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/better-sqlite3/lib/database.js:9:24)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:996:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/better-sqlite3/lib/index.js:2:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:996:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/packages/ontap/etl/store/queries-util.js:2:12)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:996:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18) {
  tries: [
    '/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/better_sqlite3.node',
    '/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/Debug/better_sqlite3.node',
    '/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/Release/better_sqlite3.node',
    '/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/better-sqlite3/out/Debug/better_sqlite3.node',
    '/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/better-sqlite3/Debug/better_sqlite3.node',
    '/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/better-sqlite3/out/Release/better_sqlite3.node',
    '/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/better-sqlite3/Release/better_sqlite3.node',
    '/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/default/better_sqlite3.node',
    '/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/better-sqlite3/compiled/15.13.0/darwin/x64/better_sqlite3.node',
    '/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/better-sqlite3/addon-build/release/install-root/better_sqlite3.node',
    '/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/better-sqlite3/addon-build/debug/install-root/better_sqlite3.node',
    '/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/better-sqlite3/addon-build/default/install-root/better_sqlite3.node',
    '/Users/avive/Desktop/dashboard/node_modules/better-sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v88-darwin-x64/better_sqlite3.node'
  ]
}

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I guess those two are somehow connected, but I can't solve that, tried changing/upgrading better-sqlite3 version, with no luck.

Thanks a lot